# Issue with GLX/X11 on Ubuntu not showing correct Window Contents

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, opengl

I'm in the process of porting my engine across to Linux support.

I can successfully create a window, and set up an OpenGL context however, the contents of the window are whatever was displayed behind it at the time of creation. NOTE: This is not a transparent window, if I drag the window around it still contains an 'image' of whatever was behind it at the time of creation. (See attached image).

Now I'm not sure where the issue could be, however I'm not looking for a solution to a specific issue in my code, mainly just any insight from other Linux/GLX developers who may have seen a similar issue and might know where I should start looking?

I stripped all the code in my update function right down to just be:

glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glXSwapBuffers(dpy, win);

With no joy. My first thought was that it was garbage, but with just those calls I'd expect to the see the glClearColor().

glGetError() returns no errors anywhere in my application.

Immediately after glXCreateContext() I then call glXMakeCurrent() and calling glGetIntegerv() with GL_MAJOR_VERSION and GL_MINOR_VERSION returns 4 and 2 (4.2) respectively which indicates the GL context has been created successfully.

I tried having a glXMakeCurrent() call immediately before I try my glClear/glXSwapBuffers() but to effect.

Further info!, this is a multithreaded application, however all X11/GLX/OpenGL calls are only made by a single thread. I have also tried calling XInitThreads() from the main application thread, and from the Rendering thread with no luck either.

[image]

Code for Creating Window

```
bool RenderWindow::createWindow(std::string title, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{
    std::cout << "createWindow() called" << std::endl;

    this->m_Width = width;
    this->m_Height = height;

    this->m_Display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    if (this->m_Display == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to connect to X Server" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    this->m_Root = DefaultRootWindow(this->m_Display);

    this->m_Active = true;

    XSetErrorHandler(RenderWindow::errorHandler);

    return true;
}
```

Code for initialising OpenGL Context

```
bool RenderingSubsystem::initialiseContext()
{
    if(!this->m_Window)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to initialise context because there is no Window" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    this->m_Window->createWindow(this->m_Window->GetTitle(), this->m_Window->GetWidth(), this->m_Window->GetHeight());

    int att[] = { GLX_RGBA, GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 24, GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, None };
    this->m_VI = glXChooseVisual(this->m_Window->GetDisplay(), 0, att);

    if (this->m_VI == NULL) 
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to initialise context because no suitable VisualInfo could be found" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    this->m_CMap = XCreateColormap(this->m_Window->GetDisplay(), this->m_Window->GetHandle(), this->m_VI->visual, AllocNone);
    this->m_SWA.colormap = this->m_CMap;
    this->m_SWA.event_mask = ExposureMask;

    std::cout << "Width: " << this->m_Window->GetWidth() << " Height: " << this->m_Window->GetHeight() << std::endl;
    this->m_Wnd = XCreateWindow(this->m_Window->GetDisplay(), this->m_Window->GetHandle(), 0, 0, this->m_Window->GetWidth(), this->m_Window->GetHeight(), 0, this->m_VI->depth, InputOutput, this->m_VI->visual, CWColormap | CWEventMask, &this->m_SWA);

    XMapWindow(this->m_Window->GetDisplay(), this->m_Wnd);
    XStoreName(this->m_Window->GetDisplay(), this->m_Wnd, this->m_Window->GetTitle().c_str());

    this->m_DC = glXCreateContext(this->m_Window->GetDisplay(), this->m_VI, NULL, GL_TRUE);

    if(this->m_DC == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to create GL Context" << std::endl;
        return false;
    }

    glXMakeCurrent(this->m_Window->GetDisplay(), this->m_Window->GetHandle(), this->m_DC);

    int major, minor; 
    glGetIntegerv( GL_MAJOR_VERSION, &major ); 
    glGetIntegerv( GL_MINOR_VERSION, &minor );

    std::cout << "InitialiseContext complete (" << major << "." << minor << ")" << std::endl;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sounds an awful lot like you have a single-buffered pixel format. Can you actually include the code you use to setup your render context?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman I've edited my original answer to include the two methods responsible for creating the window, and then creating the context. As you can see when generating the VisualInfo I request that it is double buffered.

Comment: Regarding the "new" way to create a context with GLX, there is [`glXChooseFBConfig`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXChooseFBConfig.xml). This was introduced in GLX 1.3 (which is ancient, so pretty safe to assume your system will support). The *key* difference between the two is that the attribute list is setup in a key/value pair in `glXChooseFBConfig`, so instead of `GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER` existing on its own, you have to pair it with a `True` or `False` value. Using the new part of the GLX API *might* help you, but I doubt it will change anything.

Comment: Are there other functions that I'd need to change as well? Or is it just that one?

Comment: `GLXFBConfig` has an X Visual associated with it for window types, so after selecting an FB Config you would have to call [`glXGetVisualFromFBConfig (...)`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXGetVisualFromFBConfig.xml). Be aware that `glXChooseFBConfig` will potentially return more than one FB config if there are multiple configs that match your criteria. This is all basic stuff that should be covered in any working tutorial that shows you how to get a GL3+ render context using X.